# Join with table in another database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to join with table in another database but do not know its name, I only get it from procedure parameter. So I want to do something like this:

```
select * from [DB1].dbo.[Table1] t1 
inner join [@DBName].dbo.[Table2] t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.status = @status;
```

Or even

```
select * from [DB1].dbo.[Table1] t1 
inner join [@DBNameAndTableName] t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.status = @status;
```

Is it at all possible? Or do I have to use string script and  `EXECUTE(@SQL_SCRIPT)`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE 
      @db_name NVARCHAR(150) = 'DB2'
    , @status INT = 0

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT *
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[table1] t1 
JOIN [' + @db_name +'].[dbo].[table1] t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t1.status = ' + CAST(@status AS VARCHAR(5))

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT *
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[table1] t1 
JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[table1] t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t1.status = 0
```

Comment: It will be better if you include `Quotename(@db_name)` as per the article by [sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#quotestring) to avoid sql injection

Comment: I was hoping for something "more native". The only thing I change is using `REPLACE` function to insert `@DB_NAME` into `@SQL`, much cleaner for bigger scripts...